# How do I print a term list but alter the link text?

Tags: terms

I have a long list of taxonomy terms that all look like City-ST-Zip, ie: Phoenix-AZ-85043 or San-Diego-CA-92037

How do I print the list of terms so that the link URL remains intact but the link text is just the city name? ie:

```
<li><a href="http://mydomain/zip/phoenix-az-85043">Phoenix</a></li>
```

Also - A lot of cities have multiple zip codes, but I don't want to show a city name more than once.

Comment: are you ok with showing just the first occurring zip code link for any duplicate city names?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );
    $term_name_array = array();
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_name_explode = explode("-",$term->term_name);
            $myterm_name='';
            for($i=0;$i<count($term_name_explode)-2;$i++){
               $myterm_name.=" ".$term_name_explode[$i];
            }
            $myterm_name = ltrim($myterm_name);
        if(in_array($myterm_name,$term_name_array))
            continue;
        $term_name_array[] = $myterm_name;
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id)?>"><?php echo $myterm_name;?></a></li>
        <?
    }
?>
```

Comment: this does not take care of unique city names, and the 'explode' solution will be problematic with terms such as the given example 'San-Diego-CA-92037'

Comment: @Michael have edited my answer...

Comment: I am not able to get this code to work.  Is there a variable  that I need to replace with the actual name of the taxonomy "zip-code"?

Comment: in the code, have you specified your taxonomy for:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: When i use Rajeev's answer all that is returned is one bullet point from a list with no text.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but after spending all day on this, I think I found a better approach (or at least a working approach).  I am sure that is a cleaner way to do the pre_replace and I have not solved the duplicate term problem, so I will leave this question open hoping someone will provide an even better answer.

```
<?php

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'zip-code', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $name = $term->name;
    $name = str_replace("-", " ", $name);
    $name = preg_replace('/\b[A-Z]{2}\b /', '', $name);
    $name = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $name);
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'zip-code').'" title="">'.$name.'</a></li>';
}

?>
```